# Scala: Extending inner class, without reference to outer class

Tags: scala, inner-classes

I can extend an inner class/trait inside the outer class or inside a class derived from the outer class. I can extend an inner class of a specific instance of an outer class as in:

```
class Outer
{
  class Inner{}
}

class OtherCl(val outer1: Outer)
{
  class InnA extends outer1.Inner{}
}
```

Note: even this seems to compile fine producing very interesting possibilities:

```
trait OuterA
{ trait InnerA } 

trait OuterB
{ trait InnerB }

class class2(val outerA1: OuterA, val outerB1: OuterB)
{ class Inner2 extends outerA1.InnerA with outerB1.InnerB }
```

But this won't compile:

```
class OtherCl extends Outer#Inner
```

As far as I can see I'm trying to extend a parametrised class where the type parameter is an instance of the outer class so something to the effect of

```
class OtherCl[T where T is instance of Outer] extends T.Inner
```

**So is the anyway to extend an inner class/ trait that's inside an outer trait/class without reference to the outer trait/class?**

I am not looking to instantiate the derived inner class without an instance of the outer class only declare its type.

Comment: What would you want the behavior to be if the inner class made reference to the outer class's members?

Comment: @TravisBrown Same as usual. I'm not looking to instantiate the derived inner class without an instance of the outer class only declare its type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a trait with a [self-type](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124) to do something similar. Suppose for example that we have the following:

```
class Outer(val x: Int) {
  class Inner {
    def y = x
  }
}
```

And we want to add some functionality to `Inner` without having an `Outer` around:

```
trait MyInner { this: Outer#Inner =>
  def myDoubledY = this.y * 2
}
```

Now when we instantiate an `Inner` we can mix in `MyInner`:

```
scala> val o = new Outer(21)
o: Outer = Outer@72ee303f

scala> val i = new o.Inner with MyInner
i: o.Inner with MyInner = $anon$1@2c7e9758

scala> i.myDoubledY
res0: Int = 42
```

It's not exactly what you want, but close.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have to play around with it, as my code has further complexity. I'm not sure if I've tried something like that already or not.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but with path dependent type (available on 2.10 or on 2.9 with -Ydependent-method-types flag you can do:

```
class Outer { class Inner {}; def create = new Inner }
def foo[T <: Outer](x: T) = x.create
```

Hope that's help

Comment: Ah. I've just clocked it. My first contact with Scala was at 2.9.2 Final. I just assumed that path dependant types had been fully enabled since 2.8 and that I was working with a pretty mature feature.