# Scala Type Parameter Syntax

Tags: scala, inner-classes, type-parameter

(TL;DR Look at the bottom code snippet and the errors below it)

Alright so I believe I have a simple problem, but I'm new to Scala and can't see it.

Project summary: I'm making an AbstractRoad class that contains an inner class, Builder. Other classes will extend this one, such as Highway, and they will also have Builders.

AbstractRoad has a type parameter A that can be any builder inside a class that extends AbstractRoad. This way all my methods I write in AbstractRoad#Builder will be applicable to different subclasses' builders. Those subclass builders will extend the primary AbstractRoad builder.

I'm having trouble with the Type Parameter Syntax, I'm getting a compiler error which I've listed below.  Here are my two classes, AbstractRoad:

```
class AbstractRoad[A <: AbstractRoad[A]#Builder[A]] {
  abstract class Builder[A]{
  }
}
```

And Highway:

```
class AbstractRoad[A <: AbstractRoad[A]#Builder[A]] {
  abstract class Builder[A]{
  }
}
```

Compiling these results in two errors, essentially telling me that I should add type parameters to AbstractRoad's usage in Highway.Scala.Feel free to paste them into an IDE to see the compiler error.  Fair enough. I added one to Highway (also requested by the compiler), and the two references to AbstractRoad. 
This resulted in the following edit to Highway.Scala: (AbstractRoad is unchanged)

```
class Highway[T] extends AbstractRoad[T]#Builder[Highway[T]#Builder] {
  abstract class Builder extends AbstractRoad[T]#Builder[Builder] {
    }
}
```

But now I get two weird compiler messsages, here they are:

```
Error:(1, 42) AbstractRoad[T] is not a legal prefix for a constructor
class Highway[T] extends AbstractRoad[T]#Builder[Highway[T]#Builder] {
                                         ^
Error:(1, 61) illegal cyclic reference involving class Highway
class Highway[T] extends AbstractRoad[T]#Builder[Highway[T]#Builder] {
                                                            ^
Error:(2, 50) AbstractRoad[T] is not a legal prefix for a constructor
  abstract class Builder extends AbstractRoad[T]#Builder[Builder] {
                                             ^
```

I'm trying to follow the Compiler's messages, but I can't seem to resolve any of these. Feel free to paste the code into an IDE yourself, the code you see here is all that exists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't your Highway signature just be: `class Highway[T <: AbstractRoad[T]#Builder[T]] extends AbstractRoad[T]` You seem to want to extend AbstractRoad not the Builder.

Comment: @Samar hey that helped! I'm down from three errors to one.  

And now the single error is::

`Error:(2, 50) AbstractRoad[T] is not a legal prefix for a constructor
 abstract class Builder extends AbstractRoad[T]#Builder[Builder] {
                                                 ^`

Comment: I don't think its possible to extend the inner class the way you are trying to achieve. There are some other ways to achieve similar functionality. Check this question: [extending-inner-class-without-reference-to-outer-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963909/scala-extending-inner-class-without-reference-to-outer-class)